# Vectorized type conversion for autocorrelation

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I have a simple task as part of a larger autocorrelation DSP system - to convert from signed 16-bit integer audio samples to floating-point. This part is quite self-contained:

```
#include <cblas.h>

typedef int16_t sample_t;

void consume(const sample_t *samples, int N, int rate)
{
    float *input = calloc(N, sizeof(float)),
         *output = calloc(N, sizeof(float));
    assert(input);
    assert(output);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        input[i] = (float)samples[i];

    // BLAS processing of 'input'

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        output[i] = cblas_sdot(  // Standard CBLAS call
            N-i,     // N
            input,   // X
            1,       // incX
            input+i, // Y
            1        // incY
        );
    }
}
```

Due to external constraints - the hardware only supports `S16_LE` samples - ALSA cannot do this conversion for me, nor can `cblas` accept integer types; so I'm stuck doing this myself. I've not found anything in `gsl` or `cblas` that runs vectorized type conversion.

I'm also not in love with having to loop over a level-1 dot product, but I've not been able to find a good way in BLAS to represent a single level-2 (matrix-vector) multiplication where the matrix is just a heavily-aliased single vector.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does the function `cblas_sdot()` do? Do floating point errors matter `input+i`? Note: the first question is about this question being on-topic for CR.

Comment: `cblas_sdot` is a standard method of the CBLAS library. If you think it would improve clarity, I can include the header file statement and call this out in the description.

Comment: @pacmaninbw floating-point errors don't matter _all_ that much, though the addition you indicated is pointer addition, not floating-point addition.

Comment: Yes `include the header file statement and call this out in the description.` I don't see where rate is used in the function.

Answer (score 2):

1. If this code goes into production then the asserts for the success of `calloc()` will be optimized out of the code if the code is optimized. Prefer if statements with calls to `fprintf(stderr,`.
2. The parameter `rate` is never used, this can lead to maintenance errors in the future.
3. For maintenance reasons the ability of someone else to understand the code I would suggest using `&input[i]` rather than `input+` in the function call.

Comment: What's the mechanism by which `assert` gets dropped?

Comment: Asserts are implemented as macros and are assumed to be debug tools. The macros go to blank code if the the debug flag isn't used.

Comment: For the gcc tool chain, what is the debug flag? Just DEBUG?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: So it's not a debug flag; it's a non-debug flag - NDEBUG.

Comment: Code compiled with -g will use the assert macro, code compiled without the -g flag shouldn't use the macro and code compiled with any -O will definitely not use the macro.